# How to override operator <<?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

hey, i have overridden `operator<<` and when i'm trying to use it in a print method (const) i'm getting an error :

the overriden operator :

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, Date& toPrint)
{
    return os << toPrint.GetDay() << "/" << toPrint.GetMonth() << "/" << toPrint.GetYear();
}
```

where i'm trying to use it :

```
void TreatmentHistory::TreatmentHistoryPrint() const
{
    cout << m_treatmentDate << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: red line under << before m_treatmentDate, when i'm stepping on it the error is : no operator "<<" matches this operands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using your `operator<<` in a `const` member function, thus `m_treatmentDate` is `const` (unless declared `mutable`). You need to fix your `operator<<` to take `const` arguments:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Date& toPrint);
```

Note that for this to work `GetDay()`, `GetMonth()` and `GetYear()` have to be `const` member functions as well.